# Power demand beyond maximum deliverable power

Tags: power-supply, mains

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmuTWJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We got an elementary dc power system as shown in the figure. The maximum transferable power P_max is 0.5W. Is it possible to vary the load R2 to achieve an assumed maximum power demand of 0.55W. If possible, how? If not why do we get voltage instability in power system?

Comment: What is "maximum transferable power P_max is 0.5W"? Transferable by whom and where? By the power supply? So how can you achieve 0.55W out of 0.5W? And achieve where?

Comment: Is R1 a resistor external to the power supply, or does R1 represent the internal source impedance of a practical voltage source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If not why do we get voltage instability in power system?

Using your example of a 1V dc source in series with a 0.5 ohm resistor and an unknown load resistor, maximum power is consumed by the load resistor when it exactly equals 0.5 ohms. Overall power supplied by the 1V source is 1 watt shared equally by the two resistors.

Now imagine what mayhem there would be if the AC power system, in order to supply full demand, had to "burn off" the same amount of power as that taken by consumers.

This of course never happens - the power grid doesn't need to have a series resistance of 0.5 ohms (using your example) - it could be as low as 0.000001 ohms (just for arguments sake) then, in order to deliver 0.5 watts to the load, the load has to be about 2 ohms because: -

Power = \$ \dfrac{volts^2}{R_1+R_2}\$ = \$ \dfrac{1^2}{0.000001+2}\$ = 0.499998 watts.

The load current will be almost 0.5 amps and the power dissipated in the 0.000001 ohm resistor will be negligible.

Answer (score 1):

```
R = R1 + R2 = U / I

P = U * I = U² / R = 0.55 W = 1 V / R

R = 1 V / 0.55 W ~= 1.82 Ohm
```

Answer: yes, you can dial your R2 so that both resistors together could draw enough current  to "consume" 0.55 W of power, which will however not happen if your supply does not supply as much.